# 2D objects distribution algo

Tags: algorithm, gis, graphics2d

I have to align elements in such a way to avoid their intersection, but not moving them too far:

[image: Before and after]

For simplicity, elements are rectangular (actually bounding boxes). Elements can move only by it's normal vector (can be any angle).

**Is there any well-known algorithm, that can used here?** About 50-200 elements have to be aligned each time (delay is matter, it should be a few milliseconds), and I don't think, that brute force is a good idea (but didn't try yet)

Going deeper: I have to implement street's name labeling. Let's say, I have vector lines (streets), and now, text should be displayed along those vectors (it can be rotated, not twisted). But text shouldn't overlap much, so I have to move it along its vector line . Maybe some algo for this stuff?

All it happens in run-time, when user navigates over the streets.

PS: I use Qt (simple QPainter, not the graphic framework)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, after long time, I found something suitable: [Automatic label placement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_label_placement), [Dynamic Label Placement in Practice](http://ceur-ws.org/Vol-1136/paper6.pdf)